# Cannot have a SlugRelatedField to a FileField in a DRF Serializer?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a Model w/ a foreign-key relationship to another Model w/ a FileField.  I am unable to serialize the 1st model using a serializer w/ a `SlugRelatedField` to the file of the 2nd model.  Here is some code:

**models.py:**

```
class Foo(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, blank=True, null=True)

class Bar(models.Model):
  file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="some_path")
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Foo
    fields = ("name", "bar")

  bar = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field="file")
```

But when I try to serialize an instance of `Foo` I get the following sort of error:

> UnicodeDecodeError at /api/foo/1/
>
> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 1: invalid start byte

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in your code try it.

In models.py declare Bar model before Foo.

**models.py:**

```
class Bar(models.Model):
  file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="some_path")

class Foo(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, blank=True, null=True)
```

In seralizer.py define your slug-field before class meta.

**serializers.py:**

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  
  bar = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field="file")

  class Meta:
    model = Foo
    fields = ("name", "bar")
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  It has had no effect.